# Why does this piece of code always return "no_conflict"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

I wrote a method as follows:

```
detectNameConflict: function() {
    var existing_filenames = this.element.find('ul.existing_files > li');
    if (existing_filenames.length > 0) {
        var try_name = this.element.find('div.target_filename').text().trim();
        existing_filenames.each(function(index, el) {
            if ($(el).text() == try_name) {
                return "contain_conflict";
            }
        });
    } else {
      return "no_conflict";
    }
},
```

This code doesn't work, because it **always** returns "no_conflict", even when there is a naming conflict.

note: `this.element` is from jQueryUI widget factory. It refers to the DOM element on which the widget instance attached.

Comment: By the way, is this multiple return point pattern considered bad practice in Javascript?

Comment: Multiple return points are perfectly acceptable, but it doesn't work from inside nested functions. Your `"contain_conflict"` is not returning from the outer function, it's returning from the inner function you created.

Comment: The only thing `.each()` uses the return value for is deciding whether to keep looping. If you return `false` the loop stops, otherwise it keeps going.

Comment: The only time it returns `no_conflict` is when `existing_filenames` is empty. When `length > 0`, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: console.log() is your friend, see why the check is never valid. Seems like `var existing_filenames = this.element.find('ul.existing_files > li');` is returning 0 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the jQuery collection into an array, then use the Javascript [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to test if any of them match `try_name`.

```
detectNameConflict: function() {
    var try_name = this.element.find('div.target_filename').text().trim();
    var existing_filenames = this.element.find('ul.existing_files > li').toArray();
    if (existing_filenames.some(function(el) {
        return $(el).text() == try_name;
    })) {
        return "contain_conflict";
    } else {
        return "no_conflict";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this "exiting predicate instead of the procedure" stuff only in Javascript? I've never seen such problem in Python. Although I admit that I'm a beginner for both languages. Just want to clarify this piece of knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: In Python, if you call a lambda from another function, and the lambda has `return`, it will just return from the lambda, not the calling function.

Answer (score -1):

Your return statement for `"contain_conflict"` exits the predicate, not the procedure as a whole, so each continues to loop after a conflict is detected.  You need to either use a `for` loop or exception-based control flow (seeing as JavaScript lacks `goto`).

**Update**

Barman has pointed out in the comments above that you can stop the looping by returning `false` from your predicate.  Prefer that to exceptions; I wasn't aware of that functionality when I wrote this answer.

**End Update**

A for loop:

```
detectNameConflict: function()
{
    var existing_filenames = this.element.find('ul.existing_files > li');
    if (existing_filenames.length > 0)
    {
        var try_name = this.element.find('div.target_filename').text().trim();
        for(var filename in existing_filenames)
        {
            if ($(filename).text() == try_name)
            {
                return "contain_conflict";
            }
         }
    }
    return "no_conflict";
}
```

Exception-based flow:

```
detectNameConflict: function()
{
    var existing_filenames = this.element.find('ul.existing_files > li'); 
    if (existing_filenames.length > 0)
    {
        var try_name = this.element.find('div.target_filename').text().trim();
        try
        {
            existing_filenames.each(function(index, el)
                {
                    if ($(el).text() == try_name)
                    {
                        throw "contain_conflict";
                    }
                });
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return "no_conflict";
}
```

Comment: Does not account for OPs real issue

Comment: @epascarello: Care to elaborate?

Comment: *because it always returns "no_conflict"* - means it is always in the else... means the if statement is always false

Comment: Fair enough. That is a problem too.

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on array-like objects!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)